# jQuery: Initial data for rating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a pretty stuff for rating entries: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/. It's good and easy. But I still need some more.

My code:

```
<div data-rating="4/5" class="entry"></div>
```

Desired function:

```
function init_rating(rate) { //... }
$(".entry").html( init_rating($(this).attr("data-rating")) );
```

Thanks much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
function init_rating(selector) {
    var entry = $(selector);

    var output = "";
    var input = "<input name=\"star\" type=\"radio\" class=\"star\""
    var checked = " checked=\"checked\"";
    var close = "/>";

    var params = entry.attr("data-rating").split("/", 2);
    var rating = parseInt(params[0]);
    var total = parseInt(params[1]);

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        output += input;
        if (i == rating - 1) output += checked;
        output += close;
    }

    entry.html(output);
    $('input[type=radio].star').rating();
}

init_rating(".entry");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qcxvW/20/